# Symfony2 : JFSF upload bundle file input NULL

Tags: file-upload, symfony, bundle

I follow the [JFSF tutorial](http://blog.jeromefath.com/2011/11/28/bundle-symfony2-pour-la-gestion-de-vos-uploads-avec-doctrine2/) to install JFSF upload bundle .
Step by step, I made it and no error.

But when I try to do the same in an existing bundle, my form cannot be validated for some reason, my file input is always **NULL**.

Maybe there is a bug with the **services.yml** with the arguments configuration binding the entity. If you want specific code, ask me but the only difference (in theory) is just the entity name, the bundle name.

This bundle is very useful for handling upload process.
Someone has already tried it ?

If I var_dump my entity in my createAction() in my controller just before isValid() method (I use a crud form generated by the console) :

```
object(Toto\GestionSiteBundle\Entity\People)#368 (4) 
{ 
    ["filePhoto"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#12 (7) 
    { 
        ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> bool(false) 
        ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(7) "95.jpeg" 
        ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
        ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(73987) 
        ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=> int(0) 
        ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpKH4PQo" 
        ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(9) "phpKH4PQo" 
    } 
    ["id":"Toto\GestionSiteBundle\Entity\People":private]=> NULL 
    ["nom":"Toto\GestionSiteBundle\Entity\People":private]=> string(4) "cleo" 
    ["photo":"Toto\GestionSiteBundle\Entity\People":private]=> NULL 
}
```

The browser returns me an exception :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO People (nom, photo) VALUES (?, ?)' with params {"1":"cleo","2":null}:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'photo' cannot be null
```

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of no result,

I give up this bundle and I try **VichUploaderBundle**.
In 5 minutes, I could upload my first image.

This bundle sounds good !